# Defining vs declaring class

Tags: c++, class, declaration, definition

Please, tell me whether I'm right or not.

When I'm asked to **declare** a class:

```
class Foo{
    int foo, bar;
public:
    Foo();
    Foo(int arg1, int arg2);
    void doSomething();
    int returnSomething();
    ~Foo();
};
```

but when I'm asked to define a class:

```
class Foo{
    int foo, bar;
public:
    Foo(){};
    Foo(int arg1, int arg2):foo(arg1),bar(arg2){
        //body
    }
    void doSomething(){
       //body
    }
    int returnSomething(){
        return 0;
    };
    ~Foo(){
     // e.g. free the memory
     }
};
```

btw. should I put an initialization list in a declaration or definition or both of them?

Comment: You are using inline methods. Only use them fr simple things (e.g. getters/setters). Otherwise put them in a .cpp file not the header file

Comment: @TomDavies92 My answer shows the canonical way to split the declaration and definition of a class into header and source file, respectively.

Comment: There is some confusion in terminology here. I added an answer to clarify what class declarations and definitions are. Both your declarations are definitions, so technically you could provide either when asked to "define a class".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is some confusion in terminology. A *declaration* can be a *definition* So both your examples are both *declarations* and *definitions* of `class Foo`. Whether a class definition defines the class' members is another matter. Your first example only declares the member functions and defines the data members, while your second one defines all members.

This is a class declaration that is *not* a class definition:

```
class Foo;
```

This is all laid out in **3.1 Declarations and Definitions [basic.def]**. Taking the most relevant example from that clause:

```
struct X         // defines X
{
  int x;         // defines non-static data member x
  static int y;  // declares static data member y
  X() : x(0) {}  // defines a constructor of X
};
```

So you can see that the above counts as a class definition.

> should I put an initialization list in a declaration or definition or both of them?

Again, this suffers from the same confusion in terminology. The important thing to note is that the initialization list can only be in the constructor's *definition*. So once you add one to a constructor declaration, this declaration becomes a definition too, and you need to add a body to it.

Answer (score 1):

> Please, tell me whether I'm right or not.

The first one is a *declaration* and a *definition* of the class, and the second one is both a *declaration* of the class, member functions and member objects and a *definition* of its member functions.

To only define member functions, you can use the:

```
<return type> <class_name>::<function_name>(...) {...}
```

syntax.

---

> Should I put an initialization list in a declaration or definition or both of them?

Initializations lists for the constructor should only be placed in the definition of the function.

Comment: yes, I know :). It's just for an example. Thank you for the explanation :)

Comment: My understanding is that both examples are both declarations *and* definitions of the class (not necessarily its members). See **3.1 Declarations and Definitions [basic.def]**.

Comment: I was pointing it out because your first sentence, while logically correct, implies that the first one is not a definition.

Answer (score 0):

**Edit:** @juanchopanza showed me that I was confusing the terms declaration and definition, so I typed up a whole explanation that's not quite correct. I'm correcting it here mostly so I don't forget the difference between declaration and definition myself.

<strike>Your first sample is a declaration, the second is declaration and definition in one.</strike>

Both of your samples define `Foo`. The difference is that in your first file, you're only declaring the member functions, but in the second, you're actually defining them.

The actual way to declare `Foo` is `class Foo;`. To define `Foo` use `class Foo { ... };`.

Note that a **definition can replace a declaration**, i.e. when you define X, you're also declaring it.

The following is how declarations and definitions are typically split across a header and source file pair in practice.

**foo.hpp** (defining `Foo`, but only declaring its functions)

```
#ifndef __FOO__
#define __FOO__

class Foo
{
        int foo, bar;
    public:
        Foo();
        Foo(int arg1, int arg2);
        void doSomething();
        int returnSomething();
        ~Foo();
};

#endif
```

**foo.cpp** (member function definitions)

```
#include "foo.h"

Foo::Foo()
{
}

Foo::Foo(int arg1, int arg2) :
    foo(arg1),
    bar(arg2)
{
    //body
}

Foo::~Foo()
{
    // e.g. free the memory
}

void Foo::doSomething()
{
    //body
}

int Foo::returnSomething()
{
    return 0;
};
```

It does not matter where (`foo.hpp` or `foo.cpp`) you define each particular function, as long as you only define the function once. Either define it in `foo.hpp` or `foo.cpp`, *but not both*.

**Your question on initialization lists**

Think about it: if you put an initialization list on the declaration of a constructor, it has become both declaration *and* definition.

For example, instead of defining

```
Foo::Foo(int arg1, int arg2) :
    foo(arg1),
    bar(arg2)
{
    //body
}
```

in the source file, I could have defined it in the header:

```
class Foo
{
    ...
    Foo(int arg1, int arg2) :
        foo(arg1),
        bar(arg2)
    {
        //body
    }
    ...
};
```

The only difference is that I didn't use `::`, the scope operator. You don't put `ClassName::` in front of functions that you declare or define define inside a class definition, because the compiler already recognizes them as being scoped to the class.

Comment: Both examples in OP's code are both declarations *and* definitions. `class Foo;` would be a declaration but not a definition.

Comment: Thanks. This stuff is quite confusing. They should invent a word for things that are both declarations and definitions.

Comment: @juanchopanza Edited to prevent dissemination of misinformation. At least I was right about the initialization lists. :)